# ReactJS - Hide part of page under authorization

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a ReactJS application (my first) and i need to hide some part of my pages due to authorization.

For example i have a menu on left and some `li` should be under authorization.

Right now i didnt find some API for this purpose, just something for "Login".

For example:

```
<ul>
  <authorization hasRole="simple_user">
    <li>Read Post</li>
  </authorization>
  <authorization hasRole="registerd_user">
    <li>Create Post</li>
  </authorization>
  <authorization hasRole="admin_user">
    <li>Delete Post</li>
  </authorization>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looking for something like this?

    `{this.props.isAuthorized ? <li>show this</li> : <li />}`

Comment: I was thinking something more "sophisticated"... check my update

Answer (score 2):

You can use `switch` statement.

```
class HideMe extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      isAuthorized: false,
      role: ''
    };
    this.checkAuto = this.checkAuto.bind(this);
    this.autorization = this.autorization.bind(this);
  }

  checkAuto(e){
        // of course you should send some request to the server
      // and i just simulate it : "admin", "user", "SEO"
    console.log(e.target.value)  
    switch(e.target.value) {
      case 'admin':  
            this.setState({isAuthorized: true, role: 'admin'});
        break;
      case 'user':  
                this.setState({isAuthorized: true, role: 'user'});
        break;
            case 'SEO':
        this.setState({isAuthorized: true, role: 'SEO'});
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({isAuthorized: false, role: ''});
        break;
    }  
  }
  autorization(){
    console.log(this.state.isAuthorized, this.state.role)
    if (this.state.isAuthorized && this.state.role === "admin")
      return <div className="admin">This is Admin</div>

    if (this.state.isAuthorized && this.state.role === "SEO")
      return <div className="seo">This is SEO</div>

    if (this.state.isAuthorized && this.state.role === "user")
      return <div className="user">This is user</div>
        else
      return <div className="notuser">not Authorized</div>
  }

  render(){
    return <div>
        <label>Simulate autorization: <input type="text" onChange={this.checkAuto}/> </label>
      <hr/>
      {this.autorization()}
    </div>
  }

}

React.render(<HideMe />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[***fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/308/) example. I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Mhhhh.. so in React for now do not exists some component to handle authorization, groups etc... i have to write it "by hand"....

Comment: @Mistre83 i'm not sure, probably some libraries are exist but i havent faced with it. ReactJS allows you to do it in your own way in a quite easiest way

Answer (score 0):

The authorization component can be as below

`<ul><authorization role="simple_user" /></ul>`

It can be returned as follows

```
////////////
return (
  <div>
    {(() => {
    switch (this.props.role){
      case "simple_user":
        return <li>Read Post</li>;
    case "registered_user":
        return <li>Create Post</li>;
    case "admin_user":
        return <li>Delete Post</li>;
    default:
        return <li>Read Post</li>;
    }
  })()}
  </div>
);
```